# Proof of a formula for the period of a $\sin$ function subtracting distances

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I would appreciate it if someone could explain this demonstration of the formula for the period of the sine function: $f(x)=\sin ax$. It is as follows:

> We want to find the period for this function:
>
> $f(x)=\sin ax$
>
> Since we know the period for the sine function is $2$, if $t=ax$, we
> need to find the minimal distance that should exist between $x_1$ and $x_2$
> so that when these $x$ values are transformed into $t_1$ and $t_2$, the
> distance between them will be $2$:
>
> $|t_1-t_2|=2 ⇔|a(x_1-x_2)|=2 ⇔|a|.|(x_1-x_2)|=2 ⇔ |x_1-x_2|=2/|a|$

I know the easier explanations of the $2/|a|$ formula, but I don't understand the logic behind this one. In particular, I don't understand why $|t_1-t_2|=2$, since we're not dealing with a plain sine function (with a $2$ period), but with $f(x)=\sin ax$ whose period is not $2$.

I would be grateful if someone could explain what the logic behind this demonstration is.

Answer (score 1):

Assume, without loss of generality that $x_1 > x_2.$

Since you accept that the period of $f(x)$ is $(2\pi/a)$, 
this means that you accept the goal that $(x_1 - x_2) = (2\pi/a)$
which means that you accept the goal that $(ax_1 - ax_2) = 2\pi$.

The explanation that you excerpted had $t = ax$ which means that $t_1 = ax_1, t_2 = ax_2$.

Therefore, $t_1 - t_2 = 2\pi.$

**Addendum**
Responding to the OP's comment:

> We want to find the period for this function:
> $f(x)=\sin ax.$

Without loss of generality, $a > 0.$

In order to find the period of $f(x)$, you have to define what it means for a function to have a period.

Given a generic function $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, the specification that $r$ is the period of $g$ denotes the following:

- Constraint-1 : For all $y \in \mathbb{R}, g(y) = g(y + r)$.
- Constraint-2: $r$ is the smallest possible positive value that satisfies Constraint-1.

For example, suppose $g(y) = \sin(y).$  Then the period of $g$ would be designated as $(2\pi)$, rather than [for example] $(4\pi$).  This means that $(2\pi)$ is the smallest positive value $r$ such that for any real number $y,$ 
$g(y) = \sin(y) = \sin(y+r) = g(y+r).$

Now, the challenge is to show that the period of $f(x)$ is $(2\pi/a).$  The way to do that is to show that $(2\pi/a)$ satisfies both Constraint-1 and Constraint-2.

**Constraint-1:**
For any $x \in \mathbb{R},$ 
$f(x + [2\pi/a]) = \sin(a[x + 2\pi/a]) = \sin(ax + 2\pi) = \sin(ax) = f(x).$ 
Thus, $(2\pi/a)$ satisfies Constraint-1.

**Constraint-2:**
Suppose that there exists $s \in \mathbb{R}$, such that

- $0 < s < (2\pi/a)$ and
- For all $x \in \mathbb{R}, f(x) = f(x + s)$.

Let $u$ denote $(as) \implies u < (2\pi).$ 
Since $s$ is assumed to be the period of $f$,
for all $x \in \mathbb{R},$ 
$f(x+s) = f(x) \implies 
\sin(a[x+s]) = \sin(ax + u) = \sin(ax).$

This means that for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, 
$\sin(ax + u) = \sin(ax)$. 
This means that $u$ satisfies Constraint-1, with respect to the sine function.

This yields a contradiction, since the sine function is known to have a period of $(2\pi)$.  This means that with respect to the sine function, Constraint-2 implies that there can be no positive real number $u < (2\pi)$ that satisfies Constraint-1.

Thus, the assumption that $f(x)$ had some period less than $(2\pi/a)$ yielded a contradiction.  Therefore, $(2\pi/a)$ not only satisfies Constraint-1, but also satisfies Constraint-2.

Comment: Newbie here @user2661923, sorry for the sloppy editing. Here's what I was trying to say:

I'm sorry I wasn't clear enough before. In fact, the explanation I copied earlier doesn't accept that the period of ()=sin ax is 2π/a: this is what it actually wants to prove.

All we know is that the period of f(x)=sin x is 2π.

This is why I don't understand why all the algebra work starts with |1−2|=2π, since 2π is not the period of ()=ax

Comment: @boikie See my answer's just added Addendum.